# Suppress headers List-Unsubscribe-Post and List-Unsubscribe for transactional email with Mailjet API 3.1 and Python

Tags: mailjet

I want to suppress email headers List-Unsubscribe-Post and List-Unsubscribe for transactional emails with Mailjet.  I'm using API 3.1 and Python.  See https://dev.mailjet.com/email/guides/send-api-v31/

Answer (score 1):

Response from the vendor Mailjet on 9/7/22 via a Support Ticket that I submitted:

"While the unsubscribe link itself isn't shown in the body of the email for transactional-based sends we, and some other email service providers, are obligated to include it within the headers of all emails sent from Mailjet. Having this header is a requirement for being part of the Certified Senders Alliance (CSA) so it is unable to be removed.

If the inbox does show an unsubscribe link for a transactional-based send, this will not unsubscribe the recipient from any particular list."